# Access error logs on apache AWS EC2 Linux server

Tags: linux, bash, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm getting into my server into the right directory just fine (as `su`).

`cd /var/log/httpd`

When I `ls`, I get:

`access_log  error_log`

However, when I try `cd /error_log` or `cd error_log`, I get `bash: cd: /error_log: No such file or directory` or `bash: cd: error_log: Not a directory`.

I want to simply view the last 50 or so errors (from PHP file), but not sure how to get to it. I know I need something like `tail -n 300 error_log-20130602 | more`, but I don't know the log file name.

Comment: I recommend learning to use the `ls` command to view directory and file listings, instead of trying to guess your way around the file system.

Comment: @MarkB I did use ls as I said in my question

Comment: yeah you used it, but if you had simply added the `-l` option you would have seen that they were files, not directories. Of course your error message was telling you that as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logfile name is `/var/log/httpd/access_log` and `/var/log/httpd/error_log` with no file extension or date.

That's why you get the error message

`bash: cd: error_log: Not a directory.`

It's a file

tail or head or more will work on it just fine

last 50 errors should be in the error_log

Comment: That was exactly the issue. On another server I used in the past, I thought I recalled having a number of error logs to choose from. Thanks!

Comment: @jonmrich Also even if it was a directory `cd /error_log` would be looking for it in the root directory

Comment: Is this still around on latest version Linux 2/3.3.5? Mine has disappeared :(